# Maintaining subscript format when copying a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

How do I copy/lookup/drop down list a cell with subscript format?

EXAMPLE:

Phosphate (P2O5) should have the 2 & 5 in subscript but always returns without it.

Comment: This seems to work for me, at least copy n paste.  What version of Excel are you on?